# Creating a table to house output of multiple javascript functions

Tags: javascript

So far I have created a (some what excessive, needs a lot of editing) set of functions that return output using the getelementbyID(). What I want to do is organize the outputs of all of these functions into a small provided table that is under the one we input into, as to organize the output better. My code is as follows:

```
<body bgcolor="#ff0000">
<h2> Future Stat Checker </h2>
<p></p>
<table style="width:10%">
<tr>
<th> </th>
<th> </th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>Level</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>Nature</font></th>
<th> </th>
<th> </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "L" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<select id = "Nature" style="width: 133px">
<option> Adamant </option>
<option> Bashful </option>
<option> Bold </option>
<option> Brave </option>
<option> Calm </option>
<option> Careful </option>
<option> Docile </option>
<option> Gentle </option>
<option> Hardy </option>
<option> Hasty </option>
<option> Impish </option>
<option> Jolly </option>
<option> Lax </option>
<option> Lonely </option>
<option> Mild </option>
<option> Modest </option>
<option> Naive </option>
<option> Naughty </option>
<option> Quiet </option>
<option> Quirky </option>
<option> Rash </option>
<option> Relaxed </option>
<option> Sassy </option>
<option> Serious </option>
<option> Timid </option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>Base HP</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Base Attack</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Base Defence</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Base S. Attack</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Base S. Defence</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Base Speed</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BHP" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BD" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BSA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BSD" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "BS" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>HP IV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Attack IV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Defence IV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> S. Attack IV's</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> S. Defence IV's</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Speed IV's</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "IHP" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "IA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ID" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ISA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ISD" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "IS" />
</td>
</tr>
</html>

<tr>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>HP EV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Attack EV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Defence EV's</font></th>
<th > <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> S. Attack EV's</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> S. Defence EV's</font></th>
<th ><font family = "Verdana" color = #fff> Speed EV's</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "EHP" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "EA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ED" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ESA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ESD" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ES" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p></p>
<button onclick="HPS(); AttackS(); DefenceS(); SPAttackS(); SPDefenceS(); SpeedS();">Get Stats</button>
<p id="checkHPS"></p>
<p id="checkAS"></p>
<p id="checkDS"></p>
<p id="checkSAS"></p>
<p id="checkSDS"></p>
<p id="checkSS"></p>
<script>
function HPS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVHP = parseInt(document.getElementById("IHP").value);
    var BaseHP = parseInt(document.getElementById("BHP").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("EHP").value);
    var HPS1 = ((2*BaseHP + IVHP + EV/4 + 100) * Level) / 100 + 10
    var doneH = Math.floor(HPS1);
    document.getElementById("checkHPS").innerHTML = doneH;
}
function AttackS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVA = parseInt(document.getElementById("IA").value);
    var BaseA = parseInt(document.getElementById("BA").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("EA").value);
    var N = (document.getElementById("Nature").value);
    var Nature = 1.0;
    if (N == "Adamant" || N == "Brave" || N == "Lonely" || N == "Naughty") {
        var Nature = 1.1;
    }
    else if (N == "Bold" || N == "Calm" || N == "Modest" || N == "Timid") {
        var Nature = 0.9;
    }
    var AS = (((2*BaseA + IVA + EV/4) * Level) / 100 + 5) * Nature;
    var doneA = Math.floor(AS);
    document.getElementById("checkAS").innerHTML = doneA;
}

function DefenceS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVD = parseInt(document.getElementById("ID").value);
    var BaseD = parseInt(document.getElementById("BD").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("ED").value);
    var N = (document.getElementById("Nature").value);
    var Nature = 1.0;
    if (N == "Bold" || N == "Impish" || N == "Lax" || N == "Relaxed") {
        var Nature = 1.1;
    }
    else if (N == "Gentle" || N == "Hasty" || N == "Lonely" || N == "Mild") {
        var Nature = 0.9;
    }
    var DS = (((2*BaseD + IVD + EV/4) * Level) / 100 + 5) * Nature;
    var doneD = Math.floor(DS);
    document.getElementById("checkDS").innerHTML = doneD;
}

function SPAttackS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVSA = parseInt(document.getElementById("ISA").value);
    var BaseSA = parseInt(document.getElementById("BSA").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("ESA").value);
    var N = (document.getElementById("Nature").value);
    var Nature = 1.0;
    if (N == "Mild" || N == "Modest" || N == "Naughty" || N == "Rash") {
        var Nature = 1.1;
    }
    else if (N == "Adamant" || N == "Careful" || N == "Impish" || N == "Jolly") {
        var Nature = 0.9;
    }
    var SAS = (((2*BaseSA + IVSA + EV/4) * Level) / 100 + 5) * Nature;
    var doneSA = Math.floor(SAS);
    document.getElementById("checkSAS").innerHTML = doneSA;
}

function SPDefenceS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVSD = parseInt(document.getElementById("ISD").value);
    var BaseSD = parseInt(document.getElementById("BSD").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("ESD").value);
    var N = (document.getElementById("Nature").value);
    var Nature = 1.0;
    if (N == "Calm" || N == "Careful" || N == "Gentle" || N == "Sassy") {
        var Nature = 1.1;
    }
    else if (N == "Lax" || N == "Naive" || N == "Naughty" || N == "Rash") {
        var Nature = 0.9;
    }
    var SDS = (((2*BaseSD + IVSD + EV/4) * Level) / 100 + 5) * Nature;
    var doneSD = Math.floor(SDS);
    document.getElementById("checkSDS").innerHTML = doneSD;
}

function SpeedS() {
    var Level = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
    var IVS = parseInt(document.getElementById("IS").value);
    var BaseS = parseInt(document.getElementById("BS").value);
    var EV = parseInt(document.getElementById("ES").value);
    var N = (document.getElementById("Nature").value);
    var Nature = 1.0;
    if (N == "Hasty" || N == "Jolly" || N == "Naive" || N == "Timid") {
        var Nature = 1.1;
    }
    else if (N == "Brave" || N == "Quiet" || N == "Relaxed" || N == "Sassy") {
        var Nature = 0.9;
    }
    var SS = (((2*BaseS + IVS + EV/4) * Level) / 100 + 5) * Nature;
    var doneS = Math.floor(SS);
    document.getElementById("checkSS").innerHTML = doneS;
}
</script>

</body>
```

And I am trying to get an output table of six rows and two columns with headers in the first column, and having the outputs appear in the correct places in the second column. I can create the table and such totally fine, I just am unsure how to get the outputs to appear in the correct place. The output table will look like this (except where the inputs are now temporarily, the outputs will go):

```
<table style="width:10%">
<tr>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>HP</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>ATTACK</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>DEFENCE</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>SPECIAL ATTACK</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>SPECIAL DEFENCE</font></th>
<th> <font family = "Verdana" color = #fff>SPEED</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "EHP" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "EA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ED" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ESA" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ESD" />
</td>
<td class="mycell">
<input type = "text" style="width:133px" id = "ES" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the id's where your output is going to where you want the output to go.

```
<td id="checkHPS" class="mycell"></td>
```

Comment: Wow I am dense.. Thank you so much for the help :)